# Two dimensional list in python having similar values and merging them

Tags: python, list, merge

I have a list.

```
shopping_record_list = [
                        [2,  'TeaSet', 39.95, 5],
                        [2,  'TeaSet', 39.95, 6],
                        [34, 'CitrusCather', 19.95, 5],
                        [4,  'KnifeBlockSet', 99.95, 1],
                        [4,  'KnifeBlockSet', 99.95, 1]
                       ]
```

I need this list as

```
shopping_record_list = [
                        [2,  'TeaSet', 39.95, 11],
                        [34, 'CitrusCather', 19.95, 5],
                        [4,  'KnifeBlockSet', 99.95, 2]
                       ]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
shopping_record_list = [
  [2,  'TeaSet', 39.95, 5],
  [2,  'TeaSet', 39.95, 6],
  [34, 'CitrusCather', 19.95, 5],
  [4,  'KnifeBlockSet', 99.95, 1],
  [4,  'KnifeBlockSet', 99.95, 1]
 ]

def aggregate(list_):
  results={}
  for i in list_:
    if i[0] in results:
      results[i[0]][3] += i[3]
    else:
      results[i[0]] = i
  return results

print(aggregate(shopping_record_list))
```

Result:

```
{
  2: [2, 'TeaSet', 39.95, 11],
  34: [34, 'CitrusCather', 19.95, 5],
  4: [4, 'KnifeBlockSet', 99.95, 2]
}
```

And for the aggregated values only:

```
...

print(aggregate(shopping_record_list).values())
```

Result:

```
[
  [2, 'TeaSet', 39.95, 11],
  [34, 'CitrusCather', 19.95, 5],
  [4, 'KnifeBlockSet', 99.95, 2]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) you can do:

```
[
    [*k, sum([e[-1] for e in g])]
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(shopping_record_list, lambda x: x[:-1])
]
```

output:

```
[[2, 'TeaSet', 39.95, 11],
 [34, 'CitrusCather', 19.95, 5],
 [4, 'KnifeBlockSet', 99.95, 2]]
```